# Model Binding is not happening with DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, model-binding

Here is the link to MVC dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1E6nG

I have a property called as "Result" in my ViewModel which is a List.
**Output** is an table which can dynamically add rows & each row is an combination of different inputs( like Dropdown & Text Box).

Controller:
rows.Add(new Row() { SQ1 = "2", SQ2 = "Arun", SQ3 = "kumar" });
I am assigning Values to individual Row. In the output, I can see the values getting populated in Text Boxes( Arun & kumar) whereas the DropDown list is not showing the selected value i.e DropDownList in 1st Row should show Benz as selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional parameter to your select list, like this:

```
<td> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Result[i].SQ1, new SelectList(Model.DDlist,"Value", "Text", Model.Result[i].SQ1)) </td>
```

Select list takes an optional argument for the selected value, so you can set your selected value there.